# kotlin firebase database won't upload

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I've got a little project running for an app to keep track on my LP and cd's

thing is... I want to implement a Firebase database to store all the data in. It's not the first time I'm doing such a thing.. it is the first time i'm stuck with it tho.

here's the base code for the "add item" screen. The idea is that I'm able to attach a bit of data to the items, via textviews, spinners, images etc.

the script works flawless till the "upload image" part.. after that it'll run the firebase upload code... but nothing happens. both the succes and failure log's don't give any output.

could anybody help me with this?

```
package com.example.firebasic

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add.*
import java.util.*


class AddAlbum : AppCompatActivity(), AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private var spinner:Spinner ? = null
    private var arrayAdapter:ArrayAdapter<String> ? = null

    private var genres = arrayOf(
        "Rock",
        "Jazz",
        "Soul",
        "Metal",
        "Punk",
        "Pop",
        "alt",
        "classic",
        "other",
    )

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add)

            spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner4)
            arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.spinnerbg, genres)
            spinner?.adapter = arrayAdapter
            spinner?.onItemSelectedListener = this

            //photo
            Cover_photo.setOnLongClickListener {
                Log.d("AddAlbum", "try to show album cover")
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
                intent.type = "image/*"
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0)

                return@setOnLongClickListener true
            }

            accept_button.setOnClickListener {
                UploadtoFirebase()
            }

   }

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        var genre:String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position) as String
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "$genre", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    //uri kenmerk
    var selectedphotouri: Uri? = null

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null){
            //proceed and check image
            Log.d("AddAlbum", "photo was selected")

            selectedphotouri = data.data
            val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, selectedphotouri)
            val bitmapDrawable = BitmapDrawable(bitmap)
            Cover_photo.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable)
        }
    }

    private fun UploadtoFirebase(){
        if (selectedphotouri == null) return

        val filename = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val ref = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("/images/$filename")

        ref.putFile(selectedphotouri!!)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("AddAlbum", "succesfuly uploaded")


                ref.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    saveDataToDatabase(it.toString())
                    Log.d("AddAlbum", "File location: $it")

                }

            }

    }

    private fun saveDataToDatabase(Albumphoto: String){

        //data input
        val Artist = ArtistName.text.toString()
        val Album = AlbumName.text.toString()
        val Photo = Albumphoto
        val data = User(Artist, Album, Photo)

        //upload code
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/album/$uid")
        ref.child("01").setValue(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    Log.d("addalbum", "succesfuly saved data")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener {
                    Log.d("addalbum", "still won't work")
                }
        }



}

class User(val Artist: String, val Albumname: String, val Albumphoto: String)
```

Comment: Are you sure you have internet connection on users' device?

Comment: Im looking at the documentation and I'm confused here, the `getBitmap` method you are using accepts an `Uri` so if that is working that means that you are passing the `Uri` to the `putFile` method. This is the documentation I mention MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap Is the `setBackgroundDrawable` actually showing the image?

Comment: The backgrounddrawable works just fine.. I made a new project with a new firebase database and now it works just fine.. Probably some issues with the interlinking between android studio and firebase..